# Как вытащить id видео ссылки YouTube?

Tags: java, android

Как ссылки, например https://youtu.be/KYukvjnHxo и https://youtube.com/watch?v=KYukvjnHxo вытащить id видео и поместить его в переменную String?

Answer (score 1):

Если просто парсить строку без явных регулярок:

```
List<String> urls = Arrays.asList("https://youtu.be/KYukvjnHxo", "https://youtube.com/watch?v=KYukvjnHxo");
for (String url : urls) {
    String videoId = null;

    if (url.contains("://youtu.be/")) {
        videoId = url.split(".be/")[1];

    } else if (url.contains("://youtube.com/watch?")) {
        videoId = url.split("\\?v=")[1];
    }

    System.out.println(videoId);
}
```

---

Если с регулярками, то можно так:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("https?://youtu\\.be/(\\w+)|https?://youtube\\.com/watch\\?v=(\\w+)");

for (String url : urls) {
    String videoId = null;

    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(url);
    if (m.find()) {
        videoId = m.group(1);
        if (videoId == null) {
            videoId = m.group(2);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(videoId);
}
```

---

Результат:

```
KYukvjnHxo
KYukvjnHxo
```